# Conformally mapping a rectangle to a disc, how long becomes each side?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a rectangle of shape $3 \times 1$. Map it conformally to a disc, such that the center maps to the center.

> Approximately what fraction of the circle does the image of one of the two short sides occupy?

In other words, we ask for the harmonic measure of a short side of a rectangle.
This question appears in a [paper](http://export.arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2007.pdf), with the following answer (spoiler):

> It should be near 1/64, the probability of a planar random walker to take their first three steps to the right.
>  This is indeed close: The true value is 0.0114.

Why is this answer true? I don't get the intuition.
For example, what does this imply on an arbitrary rectangle/polygon, or asking about only part of the side?

Comment: The harmonic measure is related to the probability that a Brownian motion hits that subset of the boundary, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_measure.

Answer (score 1):

Following Martin R's hint, we subdivide each square to get a grid of the vertices of a $6 \times 2$ rectangle, and we start a random walk from the central vertex.

The probability that our first hit of the boundary will be on the upper side is close to $\frac 1{64}$, and this $6 \times 2$ case presumably approximates the fine-mesh limit well.